# Ecmascript 6 recursive function with promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, sequelize.js

I am trying to write a base class for sequelize.js. This class will associate all related tables. includeFk function realize this task. But it has a promise and should be recursive. 
Class :

```
class base {
    constructor(table, depth) {
        this._table = table;
        this._depth = depth;

    }

    includeFK(table, depth, includes) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                if (depth <= this._depth) {
                    for (var att in table.tableAttributes) {

                        table.belongsTo(m, {
                            as: m.name,
                            foreignKey: att
                        })
                        includes.push({
                            model: m
                        });

                    }
                }

                Promise.all(

                    Object.keys(table.associations).forEach(tbl => {
                            this.includeFK(table.associations[tbl].target, depth + 1, includes);
                        }

                    )).then(results => {
                    resolve(true)
                });
            } else {
                resolve(true);
            }
        });



    all(query) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            var tmp = this;
            var includes = [];

            Promise.all([
                this.includeFK(tmp._table, 1, includes),
                this.includeLang()
            ]).then(function() {

                tmp._table.findAll({
                    include: includes
                }).then(function(dbStatus) {
                    resolve(dbStatus);
                });
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Error :

> (node:25079) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 3): TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined (node:25079)
>   DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
>   the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
>   Node.js process with a non-zero exit code. (node:25079)
>   UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection
>   (rejection id: 4): TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have the handle the error from `Promise.all` because it also return a promise and you need to handle it unless you train it to the returned promise.

```
Promise.all([...])
    .then(...)
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
        reject(err);
    });
```

Edit:

```
var promiseArr = [];

Object.keys(table.associations).forEach(tbl => {
  promiseArr.push(
    self.includeFK(table.associations[tbl].target, depth + 1, includes)
  );
});

Promise.all(promiseArr)
  .then(results => {
    resolve(true)
  });
```

I also think your `this` binding isn't in the correct scope. If you get error of undefined function, try to reference `this` with a variable before calling class functions.

Example:

```
includeFK(table, depth, includes) {
    var self = this; //ref this and use it later
  ...
      ...
           self.includeFK();
```

Comment: It only handles error. But my problem is that promises don't work with recursive functions.

Comment: The first problem is that you can't get meaning error log if you don't handle the errors thrown in the promise. I believe there is something wrong with the function scope so the recursive function doesn't work properly.

Comment: Now error log is : TypeError: Cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined at Function.all (native)

Comment: Promise.all only accept iterator, you have to provide an array of promise to it. Updated the answer for you.